# Error (initialization): User ... has no home directory

Tags: init-file, linux

I just installed **GNU Emacs 23.1.1** on a new machine and copied my `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.d/` from another machine where I'm running emacs 25.1.1.

When I launch emacs it writes `Error (initialization): User <my_id> has no home directory` into a buffer. Not surprisingly, it also has not read `.emacs`.

One thing odd about this machine is that home directories are stored in `/home/`, rather than in `/mxhome/` like in the rest of my work environment, and this new machine has a symlink from `/mxhome -> /home`. I don't know if that is important.

**UPDATE:** launching with `emacs -q -l /home/my_id/.emacs` *filename* loads the `.emacs` file and avoids the error, although I don't know if it solves the problem entirely.

Emacs administration is largely a mystery to me. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you still see the problem with `emacs --no-site-file`?

Comment: Do you have a `HOME` environment variable set? If not, try setting `HOME`.

Comment: @Stefan @Drew I still see the problem with `emacs --no-site-file`. I do have `HOME` set to `/mxhome/my_id` which, as noted above, is a symlink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the idea from @glucas, I debugged the variable `init-file-user`, and came up with a temporary solution

```
alias emacs='emacs --user ""'
```

With `--user ''`, it enforced the `init-file-user` to be an empty string, then

```
(file-directory-p (expand-file-name (concat "~" init-file-user)))
```

would be properly evaluated to the correct path.

My case is really odd, and I've tried emacs-25.2, 25.3 and 26.1. They all produce the same problem. However, this problem only appears on CentOS7, but not CentOS6. So, I compared the difference in the value of `init-file-user` between the two systems, and came up with the above solution. On CentOS6, `init-file-user` is an empty string, emacs works; but on CentOS7, it's , producing error.

I still don't know how the value of `init-file-user` is initialized, the source code for [`startup.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/94e794c8d8b93a1d6813742da12135f2746ef80b/lisp/startup.el) is rather overwhelming.

Comment: Over a year later and I'm just getting back to this. Using --user "" solves my problem, or at least works around it as you described.

Comment: This worked for me too in Amazon Linux . Really weird

Answer (score 1):

I would try starting emacs with HOME set to /home/my_id (rather than the symlink), since explicitly using that path seems to work.

The error message ("user has no home directory") is coming from `startup.el`. You may be able to use `--debug-init` to investigate further.

Basically the error message implies the following is false:

```
(file-directory-p (expand-file-name (concat "~" init-file-user)))
```

You could try starting Emacs with your workaround and evaluate `(expand-file-name "~")` and `(file-directory-p (expand-file-name "~"))` and see if they are returning what you'd expect.

Comment: `env HOME=/home/my_id emacs` still throws the error. Then evaluating `(expand-file-name "~")` gives `/mxhome/my_id`, oddly. And, evaluating `(file-directory-p (expand-file-name (concat "~" init-file-user)))` is indeed nil. I will try using `--debug-init`.

Comment: Does `(expand-file-name (concat "~" init-file-user))` give you `/home/my_id/~my_id` or something like that. That's what I see with the same error message. I don't have fix yet

Comment: @zyxue it gives "/home/my_id"

Comment: Also, I found that `init-file-user` is nil

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of not resolving `~user` properly was fixed for me by [installing `nscd`](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-guix/2018-03/msg00323.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change your home path.
If your computer's OS is Windows.You can check the regedit.
The path is: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GNU\Emacs\Home
Change it to your Emacs location.

Comment: It is much easier to set the environment variable HOME in this case.